# RuntimeException handling in java web application

Tags: java, hibernate, tomcat, web-applications, wicket

I've faced an interesting aim, this aim targets the exception handling in existing web application written with wicket and hibernate frameworks, 
suppose we have web app which is deployed in server and sometimes it produces runtime exceptions, the problem is how to get and save their stacktrace to db without modifying  all classes(about 80 models and 150 views).

Hope i gave all clear.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Make sure that whatever does the saving doesn't throw a `RuntimeException` is my advice :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Wicket 1.4 and earlier

Override [`Application.newRequestCycle()`](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/Application.html#newRequestCycle%28org.apache.wicket.Request,%20org.apache.wicket.Response%29) and return a custom subclass of `WebRequestCycle` that overrides [`RequestCycle.logRuntimeException()`](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/RequestCycle.html#logRuntimeException(java.lang.RuntimeException)) in order to provide additional logging behavior for all `RuntimeException`s in your application. Notice that any uncaught `Exception` will be wrapped by Wicket in a `WicketRuntimeException` (as stated in the *Exception handling* section of [Request cycle and request cycle processor](https://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/request-cycle-and-request-cycle-processor.html)) :

There, use a Service/DAO component that will insert the exception message along with the stacktrace into the database. Remember that depending on the dbms, you might want to use a CLOB instead of a varchar type (for instance, in Oracle, a varchar column cannot hold more than 4000 bytes).

Here's an (*untested*) example:

```
public class myApplication extends WebApplication { 
    ...
    @Override
    public RequestCycle newRequestCycle(Request request, Response response) {
        return new myRequestCycle(this, (WebRequest) request, (WebResponse) response);
    }
} 

public class myRequestCycle extends WebRequestCycle { 
    ...
    @Override
    protected void logRuntimeException(RuntimeException rex) {
        super.logRuntimeException(rex);
        Writer w = new StringWriter();
        t.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(w));
        String stackTrace = w.toString();
        someService.logExceptionToDB(rex.getMessage(),stackTrace);
    } 
}
```

### Wicket 1.5 and later

See [@Cristoph's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12314525/851811)

Comment: Is there any method to handle Exception but not only RuntimeException

Comment: If I remember correctly, any uncaught `Exception` in the context of a Wicket request will end up throwing a `WicketRuntimeException`. See [Request cycle and request cycle processor](https://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/request-cycle-and-request-cycle-processor.html), specifically the _Exception handling_ section.

Answer (score 6):

You can use an `IRequestCycleListener` to log/handle your exceptions:

```
public class MyExceptionReporter extends AbstractRequestCycleListener {

    @Override
    public IRequestHandler onException(RequestCycle cycle, Exception ex) {
        // log exception here
        return null;
        // if you want to also show an error page:
        // return new RenderPageRequestHandler(new PageProvider(new ExceptionPage(ex)));
    }
}
```

Then register it in `WebApplication#init`:

```
getRequestCycleListeners().add(new MyExceptionReporter());
```

Comment: +1 Nice answer. Didn't know this was possible, I got stuck in 1.3 :( @ilya.stmn I don't think it's available in 1.4, see [RequestCycle in Wicket 1.5](https://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/requestcycle-in-wicket-15.html)

Answer (score 0):

Write a utility which uses StackTraceElement[] to give you the complete stacktrace. Use an implementation of OutputStream to push it to a CLOB object. (I don't think BLOB is needed)

Comment: Thanks , but how can i wire this utility to web app?

Comment: Are you looking for UncaughtExceptionHandler ? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler.html

Comment: I'm looking for method to handle all excetions produced by web application